# Problem in writing/inserting special symbol

Tags: unicode

I am writing text in Latex, but getting error message “Unicode character”. How to correct it?

```
K(a+b,c-2) +L(a-b,c+1)
```

Secondly, I want to use arrow therefore using command $\Rightarrow$. But instead of arrow, get the same text $\Rightarrow$. (I have included \usepackage{mathabx}

Comment: "Unicode character` is not a tex error message.  Please show the exact error message from the log file, which will say what the error is, which character is causing it, and where in teh file the error occurs.

Comment: The fragment you posted only has ascii characters so can not generate any error mentioning Unicode. This runs without error: `\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$K(a+b,c-2) +L(a-b,c+1)$
\end{document}`

Comment: Inserting arrow problem occurs inside Lising only. Outside the list it works.

Comment: don't set riddles. Make a small complete document that makes an error and show the exact error message that you get. No one can help you if you provide no information about the problem. You did not  even mention listings in your question.

Comment: $k(a − 1, b − 2),k1(b − 6, c − 1)$ .This is message LaTeX Error: Unicode character − (U+2212). Your given example works.

Comment: tha tis just a small fragment of the error message and it means you have ` −` instead of a `-` but the code you showed does not generate that error. Just replace the `−` in your unshown code with `-`. The full error message will show the full location in the file.

Answer (score 1):

This might be related to copying text (equations) from a PDF or a webpage. Try to delete the minus sign and then write it (don't copy and paste it).

For the arrow: did you include `\usepackage{amsmath}`?

(But these are really two questions...)

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted does not generate an error. You only provided an error fragment as a comment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$k(a − 1, b − 2),k1(b − 6, c − 1)$ 
\end{document}
```

Generates the error (which you have not shown)

```
! LaTeX Error: Unicode character − (U+2212)
               not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.5 $k(a −
             1, b − 2),k1(b − 6, c − 1)$
?
```

Note the error message tells you which character is causing the problem, it shows the problem line is line 5 in the input file, and that teX has read as far as the `−`.

Replace the `−` by `-`

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$k(a - 1, b - 2),k1(b - 6, c - 1)$ 
\end{document}
```

runs without error:

[image]

Comment: One could add that the dash in the original code is a minus sign which has a different Unicode codepoint than a hyphen-minus. The latter is part of the ASCII set, the former is not and therefore will throw the error in this case.